# Parsing a long column to multiple rows using RegEx?

Tags: regex, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table where the history for a file's edits is stored off, one row per file. Most of them are pipe delimited so I transform the table into a 'one row one edit' style by parsing out the fields with this sort of thing:

`LATERAL FLATTEN (INPUT => SPLIT(x.User,'|')) a`

However, annoyingly one of the fields doesn't have pipes and instead has a timestamp between edits. (it's so people in the file can see the edit history) In our SAS world, I have a job (below) that parses it out using a RegEx and looping around to do the parse/transpose.  Is such a thing doable in Snowflake?

```
data notesdata_parsed;
   rx_date = prxparse('/[ ]\d+[\/]\d+[\/](2020|2021)[ ]\d+[:]\d+[:]\d+( AM -| PM -)/');

set notesdata;
where textfield ne '';                              
   do while(1);                                 
        rx_pos  = prxmatch(rx_date,textfield);
        if rx_pos = 0 then
            do;
            textfield_new=textfield;
            output;
           leave;
        end;

        textfield_new = substr(textfield,1,rx_pos-1);
        textfield=substr(textfield,rx_pos+1);
       output;
    end;
   drop rx_date textfield rx_pos;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of exact regex you'd need in Snowflake, but you could leverage the REGEXP_REPLACE function in Snowflake to make the date into a PIPE and then do your existing  `LATERAL FLATTEN` type of thing.

Something along the lines of:

```
LATERAL FLATTEN (INPUT => SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(x.User,'{regex expression}','|'),'|')) a
```

The regex syntax in Snowflake might be a little different, so I just used a placeholder there.  I'm not an expert in Regex.

Comment: Wow thanks, yeah, use the RegEx to add the pipes and then split it.

Comment: @CalvinGraham if the answer provided by Mike helps you out, the best way to show appreciation is to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answer and if it answers the question sufficiently [mark it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to your question, to increase visibility and help other with similar questions in the future find your specific question/answer.